# Finding Limit at 0

Tags: calculus

Find $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+\sin 2x)^\frac{1}{x}-e^2}{x}$.

I use L'hopital Rule and get it equal to $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}(1+\sin 2x)^\frac{1}{x}\left[\frac{2x\cos 2x}{1+\sin 2x}-\ln(1+\sin 2x)\right]$, but it seems impossible to continue. How can I proceed from here?

By the way, the answer from Mathematica is $-2e^2$.

Comment: After your first step, you can probably use logarithms to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that using $\sin(x)=x+O(x^3)$, $\log(x)=x-\frac12 x^2+O(x^3)$ and $e^x=1+x+O(x^2)$ we can write

$$\begin{align}
(1+\sin(2x))^{1/x}&=e^{\frac1x \log(\sin(2x))}\\\\
&=e^{\frac1x (2x-2x^2+O(x^3))}\\\\
&=e^2e^{-2x+O(x^2)}\\\\
&=e^2(1-2x+O(x^2))
\end{align}$$

Comment: Another approach is L'hopital as you started. set $1+sin2x=\sqrt{2}{cos(x-\pi/4)}$. Then you can get $lim-2(\frac{ln(\sqrt{2}cos(x-\pi/4))+xtan(x-\pi/4)}{x^2}){e^2}$. Again using L'hopital we get $(-2sec^2(x-\pi/4)/2)e^2$.

Comment: @M.R.Yegan  $1+\sin(2x)\ne \sqrt{2}\cos(x-\pi/4)$.